# What does moment mean in probability?

Tags: probability

I recently learned the concepts of moments, including the $k$-order origin moment, the $K$-order central moment, and the $k+ L$-order mixed central moment. But I don't understand what it actually means and why there are these concepts that have evolved from it?  Can someone help to answer it please? Thank you.

Comment: This has a very nice answer : so consider adding some context to your question , for example where you learned this from. If it's a textbook or an online resource, mentioning it in an edit will be enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The $k$th moment of a random variable is defined as $E[X^k]$. The $k$th central moment is defined as $E[(X - E[X])^k]$. There are a few reasons we care about moments. First is that the distribution of a random variable on a bounded interval is uniquely determined by the moments so if you know every moment of a random variable, then you know the distribution. Even on unbounded intervals they give you a large amount of information on the distribution and give you a way to approximate it.

A second reason is that our empirical estimates of the moments are relatively easy to calculate, given some data. We can find the empirical estimate of the first moment really quickly—it is just the average of the data! Similarly the second moment is just the average of the squares. Since the moments determine the distribution it is often easy for parametrized distributions to find an equation for the parameters of the distribution in terms of the moments (which can then be estimated easily with the data) which leads to the "method of moments."

Mixed moments are moments involving more than one random variable. They are also useful for characterizing the joint distribution of random variables!

Comment: No, a distribution is NOT uniquely determined by the moments… there exists random variables which have the same moments but are distributed differently.

Comment: Care to give an example on a bounded interval?

Comment: @PhysicsKid there is no example on bounded intervals. Only RVs defined on unbounded intervals can have the same moments of all orders and yet fail to be identically distributed. See https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.12698.pdf (p. 17).

Comment: Exactly. Thank you!